# List of image links

Tags: nodes, media

The aim is to render page (node) with text field and list of image links:

```html
<p>some text</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href='img1.jpg'>img 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='img2.jpg'>img 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='img3.jpg'>img 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

To create content type with one text field is easy, but how to associate list of images with content type? And more, the images should be reusable, i.e. one image can be used/rendered in more nodes. Thus the images have to be content nodes as well probably.

Of course content manager must be able to associate different images to different nodes, i.e. list of image links is not static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the problem here, but maybe I'm too regular to things, or I didn't understand it correctly.
If I understood correctly, you want the content manager to have the ability to add more than one image per node, and that it will be possible to select the same images again from another node.
If so,
1. Add image field to the same content type that has the textfield in it, and in the image field configuration make it multi value
2. Use the media module so that the content manager will be able to see images that has been uploaded in the past and will be able to select it as well

About the unordered list, override the image field's templeate file and make it render as UL.

Comment: Agreed. You can also use [DS](http://drupal.org/project/ds) instead of doing a template override.